# UV map repeating on mesh when unwrapped

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I am unwrapping a mesh of a boot to get ready for texturing but I have never seen this happen before. As you can see with the pants those are using the same texture and have unwrapped fine. The scale and everything is as it should be on the boots but I can not figure out what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of what is happening]
[image: Image of shader editor]

Comment: Hello, maybe show your Shader Editor, and also make sure that you're using the good UV map?

Answer (score 1):

Under "Object Data Properties" and under "UV Maps" I deleted and made a new index and that fixed it.